# replace words in a string from an array of string

Tags: javascript, replace

i receive a string that i want to clean from some word, i tried to make a function for that but it doesn't work :

```
export const cleanArrondissements = async (city) => {

  const arrondissements = [ 'Arrondissement', 'arrondissement', '1er','2e','3e', '4e', '5e', '6e', '7e', '8e', '9e', '10e','11e','12e','13e','14e', '15e', '16e', '17e', '18e', '19e', '20e']
  arrondissements.forEach(element => {
    city.replace(element, '')
  });
  return city;
```

}

what would be the best way to do that ?

Comment: Please go read the description of how `replace` works _carefully_. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: `.replace()` returns a new string, you need to assign the string returned by `.replace()` to `city` variable ---> `city = city.replace(element, '')`

Comment: hopefully the word only appears once in the string.

Answer (score 2):

replace() method searches a string for a specified value, or a regular expression, and returns a new string where the specified values are replaced

so with replace you don't change element.You need to assign to your variable to accept replace method's changes.

```
export const cleanArrondissements = async (city) => {   
  const arrondissements = [ 'Arrondissement', 'arrondissement', '1er','2e','3e', '4e', '5e', '6e', '7e', '8e', '9e', '10e','11e','12e','13e','14e', '15e', '16e', '17e', '18e', '19e', '20e']
  arrondissements.forEach(element => {
    city=city.replace(element, '')
  });
  return city;
}
```

if you may have more than one same element in base string then you can use regex

```
city=city.replace(new RegExp(element, 'g'), '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Reduce makes it cleaner:

```
const cleanArrondissements = (city) => {
    
      const arrondissements = [ 'Arrondissement', 'arrondissement', '1er','2e','3e', '4e', '5e', '6e', '7e', '8e', '9e', '10e','11e','12e','13e','14e', '15e', '16e', '17e', '18e', '19e', '20e']
      
      return arrondissements.reduce((acc, cur) => acc.replace(cur, ""), city);
}
```